# How to make a Horizontal Scrolling Gallery

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, photo

I am new to coding but would like to make a horizontal scrolling gallery. I want it to look exactly like the one on this page: http://tessaneustadt.com/interiors#/id/i12139225 except I want white space on both ends. I want it to be responsive, just like this page.

I have search endlessly and have had many trial+errors. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
.img-wrapper{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 300px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.img-wrapper img{
    width: auto;
    height: 250px:
    margin: 20px 25px;
}
```

Search for css attribute `overflow-y: scroll`, that will allow the div to be constrained within the defined height and width.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this Library

[Sly](http://darsa.in/sly/)

And for the Responsiveness you can added customized CSS for override the styles, that used by the Library.